# i cant import "statsmodels.api" for the reason of "there's no module of Scipy.integrate sub module"

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using anaconda  Jupyter notebook 
and trina import the below.

`import os
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import scipy
import statsmodels.api as sm`

But here's the Error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-1-89daf53fdc43> in <module>
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import scipy
----> 5 import statsmodels.api as sm ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\api.py in <module>
      5 from . import tools
      6 from .tools.tools import add_constant, categorical
----> 7 from . import regression
      8 from .regression.linear_model import OLS, GLS, WLS, GLSAR
      9 from .regression.recursive_ls import RecursiveLS ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .linear_model import yule_walker
      2 
      3 from statsmodels.tools._testing import PytestTester
      4 
      5 __all__ = ['yule_walker', 'test'] ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in <module>
     38 import numpy as np
     39 from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
---> 40 from scipy import stats
     41 from scipy import optimize
     42  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>
    365 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    366 
--> 367 from .stats import *
    368 from .distributions import *
    369 from .morestats import * ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>
    171 from scipy._lib._util import _lazywhere
    172 import scipy.special as special
--> 173 from . import distributions
    174 from . import mstats_basic
    175 from ._stats_mstats_common import _find_repeats, linregress, theilslopes, siegelslopes ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py in <module>
      8 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
      9 
---> 10 from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
     11                                     rv_frozen)
     12  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in <module>
     25 
     26 # for functions of continuous distributions (e.g. moments, entropy, cdf)
---> 27 from scipy import integrate
     28 
     29 # to approximate the pdf of a continuous distribution given its cdf ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\__init__.py in <module>
     87 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     88 
---> 89 from .quadrature import *
     90 from .odepack import *
     91 from .quadpack import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.integrate.quadrature
```

so i download using Cmd.
(pip install scipy) 
Also, i already checked the anaconda navigator weather i download the scipy module, but it alrealy did.

how can i import this module?

Comment: quadrature is a function, not a module. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quadrature.html#scipy.integrate.quadrature

Comment: whats matter in my import sentence?
i tried to "import statsmodels.api" but it didnt work 
and they only say the module dont have submodule named integrate
even though i already download the scipy module

Comment: Well, your pip-instlled scipy is broken. Don't mix pip and conda. In conda-land only install conda packages.

Comment: im totallllllly love you !!! i uninstall the scipy by "pip uninstall scipy" and restart the jupyter notebook and it go on !

Answer (score 0):

`pip` and `conda` adds symlink at different locations, which can cause some confusing mix-ups.

Thus, try to have all your packages managed by one OR the other should fix the issue.